# Value mapping with hashmap and duplicate possible keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, duplicates

I'm trying to tackle a problem where I need to implement a mapping feature into our application, so it will read a series of input values and determine when it is necessary to convert them to a different set.

The input file will read as follows:

```
DXPATFST:DXPATFS:16730938:16801671

DXPATDST:DXPATDS:16730938:16801599

DXPATFST:DXPATFS:16730938:16801450
```

The real trick with this one, I'm trying to match up the first and third values with inputs coming from elsewhere in the application. When/if that match is made, then the value corresponding to the first input, gets changed over to the second, and the one corresponding to the third input, will get changed to the fourth. I have an algorithm written that will do this by parsing each line of the file, but I'm hoping for something more efficient.

I thought of implementing a hashmap to acquire each pair of values and map that way, but the problem is that there are many duplicates showing up in the third value spot, so a simple key->value system is not practical. I thought of doing a hashmap nested within a hashmap but I'm not sure how to go about executing it. Currently, I'm parsing the inputs using the colons as a delimiter with StringTokenizer, to get each set of values one at a time. I can reorder each line in any fashion I like, as long as the mappings are applied correctly. I'm pretty much stumped on this and am fresh out of ideas. Any thoughts?

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of implementing a hashmap to acquire each pair of values and map that way, but the problem is that there are many duplicates showing up in the third value spot, so a simple key->value system is not practical.

You are being vague as to what the solution you have in mind is.

Why wouldn't creating a `Pair` class and using that as the key work?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of `Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = 
    new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();` but I'm not sure what scheme to use to identify each unique value. For the outer map, I could use my first value, but for the inner map, how would that work with duplicates?
Also, I'm not sure what you mean by a "Pair" class.

Comment: Please see the question I flagged this question as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190049/using-two-or-more-objects-as-a-hashmap-key